# Why do different GNSS receivers show different measurements on the same satellite?

Tags: gps, gnss

I have two receivers + antennas pairs where I collect data from. So, each receiver outputs one RINEX file where I can look at the epoch-by-epoch measurements of pseudorange, carrier and doppler.

Why do I see such different outputs for the same satellite in the same epoch across different receivers? For example, the doppler can be 200 Hz off for the same satellite. This doesn't seem that intuitive to me. If the receivers are within a few feet of each other then I would assume that the measurements would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Noise, interference, component variations, temperature, antenna alignment and most importantly multipath propagation are different for different receivers.

So, I would expect exactly what you're seeing: estimating the properties contained in such a report is estimation from very noisy sources in multiple ways, and expected to be different

Comment: Are there any resources to learn more about this? I have a GNSS book by Misra and Enge but they don't go too much in depth about this.

Comment: I'm surprised. Chapter 5 and chapter 10 of that exact book.

Comment: I don't have the book in my private library, but should you have questions about what's written in these chapters, asking specifically would make good question posts on here or on https://DSP.stackexchange.com .